# Temporary table scope

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Say for an example if I created a procedure like below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GETVALUES (@id INT)
AS
  BEGIN
      SELECT *
      INTO   #TEMPTABLE
      FROM   products
      WHERE  id = @id

      SELECT *
      FROM   #TEMPTABLE

      DROP TABLE #TEMPTABLE
  END
```

If this procedure is run simultaneously by 3 or 4 users then will the data in `#temptable` collapse with other calls?

Comment: I started on an answer, then realized that there was a much better-written one already. VTC as a duplicate of that question/answer.

Comment: see the answer   http://stackoverflow.com/a/18614467/6224406

Comment: thank you i just thought that the temporary table created with a structure and the one  i have given above are different

Comment: It will not collapse with other calls, because # tables are on connection level, if that table was global table (## table) it would collapse, because global tables are on server level