# Naming a Temp Table with a Dynamic Date

Tags: sql

Is there a way to Name a temp table with a variable date?

For Example:

```
DECLARE @SomeDate datetime = '12/31/2016'

Select * 
into #?? 
from Table
```

The end result I'm looking for is #201612

Comment: only possible with dynamic SQL, and generally a bad idea.

Comment: why is it a bad idea?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? ("SQL" is just a query language, not a database product)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server and possibly others, temp tables (but not global temp tables) are only visible to the session. Multiple sessions can create the temp tables with the same name and they don't interfere with each other. So, possibly all you need is a fixed name.

Check this for more info:
[Scope of temporary tables in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614344/scope-of-temporary-tables-in-sql-server)