# Can't reach temp table with using prepared statement for second time

Tags: java, sql-server, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I am using temporary tables inside my code in order to [some long sequnce of reasons here] in SQL Server, Java. I was executing my sql queries with using Stament object in java. However, recently I decided to use PreparedStatement in order to avoid injection thing.

My problem is when create a temporary table with using PreparedStatement, I can not reach it with the same prepared statement again. Here is a simple illustration:

```
sql = "select * into #someTable from (select someColumns from someOtherTable where smth = ? and smth2 = ?)"
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
for(int i=0; i<parameters.size(); i++){
   preparedStatement.setString(i+1, parameters.get(i).toString());
}

this.rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Until here, it is ok. After getting ResultSet and doing something with it, or without getting a resultSet just for `preparedStatement.execute()` does not makes difference, I can not reach the #someTable object again.

```
sql = "select count(*) from #someTable"
preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
this.rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Here `this.rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();` part gives `'Invalid object name #someTable'`. I am doing all of the things above with using one Connection object only and without closing or reopening it. I need to use that temp table again. Is there any way to create temp table with PreparedStatement object in java and reuse this temp table again and again? Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Rather late to the party, but facing the same problem and finding the above answer wrong:

Read this article about the problem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-usefmtonly?view=sql-server-2017

I found that using a PreparedStatement to create the temp table wouldn't work, but if I changed to use a Statement to create the temp table it would work (even without the useFmtOnly).
So start with this (from the MS article) and build on it:

```
final String sql = "INSERT INTO #Bar VALUES (?)";
try (Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD)) {
    try (Statement s = c.createStatement()) {
        s.execute("CREATE TABLE #Bar(c1 int)");
    }
    try (PreparedStatement p1 = c.prepareStatement(sql); PreparedStatement p2 = c.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        ((SQLServerPreparedStatement) p1).setUseFmtOnly(true);
        ParameterMetaData pmd1 = p1.getParameterMetaData();
        System.out.println(pmd1.getParameterTypeName(1)); // prints int
        ParameterMetaData pmd2 = p2.getParameterMetaData(); // throws exception, Invalid object name '#Bar'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The temp table you create in the first statement exists for the scope\lifetime of that request. As soon as you call another query, you're in a different scope so it is no longer present as it would have been cleaned up.

Solutions are either make 2 requests in the same call (not great) or create a global temp table that can be accessed by the second query (still not great).

The better solution is to create a stored procedure that does everything you need, with the temp table creation, querying and tidy up encapsulated in the procedure.

PS I can't see any surrounding code, but beware of SQL Injection when building queries in code like this.

Related info:
[Scope of temporary tables in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614344/scope-of-temporary-tables-in-sql-server)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am doing all of these stuffs with using 1 connection only and without closing and reopening it.

Comment: @JollyRoger but you're making more than one call? first to create the table and second to return some data, so they have different scopes.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the call. These 2 parts of the code actually stands together in a method.

Comment: You call in to SQL Server to build the temp table on one line of code, you then  try to query that temp table on a seperate line of code. So the code can be in the same method, but you're having 2 seperate conversations with SQL Server and the temp table doesn't exist in the second conversation.

Comment: Yes that is correct, but for example if I use Statement instead of PreparedStatement, I can access more than once to the #tempTable. Does Statement object do not create another call? And I need to take some columns from #tempTable and also the count of the #tempTable. Is there any way to do these together without creating #tempTable twice?